# Upload file to S3 using Rails 5 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I have a controller method which is called on form submit. This method then calls the api for saving the data which also includes a file.
If I execute the code for file upload in my controller method before calling the api, the file gets uploaded on s3 whereas if I try to upload the file in the api, it throws an error in the controller method.

Example:
This works:

```
def formsubmitmethod
# Code for uploading a file to s3
Aws.config.update(
region: 'region_name',
credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('access_key_id','secret_access_key')
)
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'region_name')
original_filename = params['picture'].original_filename
obj = s3.bucket('bucket_name').object(original_filename)

File.open(original_filename, 'wb') do |file|
obj.put(body: params['picture'])
end
```

## Code for calling the api where the data needs to be saved.

```
@response = HTTParty.post("url_for_post_request_api", :body => { :query => params.to_json})
end
```

But if I add the same code in the method for post_request_api(url_for_post_request_api) it throws the following error:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in controller method
"\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
Stack trace of parameters:
Parameters:
{"picture"=>
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f60b6559498
@content_type="image/png",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"1.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n",
@original_filename="1.png",
@tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20161102-10689-137nvix.png>>
}
```

Note: the other parameters in the form are also a part of the parameters displayed but I have removed it for readability.

Also I would like to know how we can retrieve the file so that it can be displayed and can be downloaded.